# D3.js: how to restrict dragging of x-axis in a grouped bar chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg

Here is the link to the code http://jsfiddle.net/4tqn7162/1/   .if you drag the bars to the left or right after the width of svg  the plot completely disappears.I want restrict it without affecting the zooming operation.Can anyone help me with that.

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 300 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
```

Data used for plotting the graph

```
var data = [
   {
       "State": "CA",
       "Under 5 Years": 2704659,
       "5 to 13 Years": 4499890,
       "14 to 17 Years": 2159981,
       "18 to 24 Years": 3853788,
       "25 to 44 Years": 10604510,
       "45 to 64 Years": 8819342,
       "65 Years and Over": 4114496
   },
   {
       "State": "TX",
       "Under 5 Years": 2027307,
       "5 to 13 Years": 3277946,
       "14 to 17 Years": 1420518,
       "18 to 24 Years": 2454721,
       "25 to 44 Years": 7017731,
       "45 to 64 Years": 5656528,
       "65 Years and Over": 2472223
   },
   {
       "State": "NY",
       "Under 5 Years": 1208495,
       "5 to 13 Years": 2141490,
       "14 to 17 Years": 1058031,
       "18 to 24 Years": 1999120,
       "25 to 44 Years": 5355235,
       "45 to 64 Years": 5120254,
       "65 Years and Over": 2607672
   },
   {
       "State": "FL",
       "Under 5 Years": 1140516,
       "5 to 13 Years": 1938695,
       "14 to 17 Years": 925060,
       "18 to 24 Years": 1607297,
       "25 to 44 Years": 4782119,
       "45 to 64 Years": 4746856,
       "65 Years and Over": 3187797
   },
   {
       "State": "IL",
       "Under 5 Years": 894368,
       "5 to 13 Years": 1558919,
       "14 to 17 Years": 725973,
       "18 to 24 Years": 1311479,
       "25 to 44 Years": 3596343,
       "45 to 64 Years": 3239173,
       "65 Years and Over": 1575308
   },
   {
       "State": "PA",
       "Under 5 Years": 737462,
       "5 to 13 Years": 1345341,
       "14 to 17 Years": 679201,
       "18 to 24 Years": 1203944,
       "25 to 44 Years": 3157759,
       "45 to 64 Years": 3414001,
       "65 Years and Over": 1910571
   }];
var x0 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var x1 = d3.scale.ordinal();

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x0)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat(d3.format(".1s"));

var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
 .call(d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([1, 10]).on("zoom", zoom));

//d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
var ageNames = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "State"; });
     console.log("ageNames="+JSON.stringify(ageNames));
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.ages = ageNames.map(function(name) { return {name: name, value: +d[name]}; });
      console.log("d.ages="+JSON.stringify(d.ages));
  });

  x0.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.State; }));
  x1.domain(ageNames).rangeRoundBands([0, x0.rangeBand()]);
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { 
      console.log(" before retuen d.ages="+d.ages);
  return d3.max(d.ages, function(d) 
  { console.log("d.value;="+d.value);
  return d.value; }); 
  })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".5em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Population");

var mask = svg.append("defs")
  .append("clipPath")
  .attr("id", "mask")
    .append("rect")
    .attr({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
      width: width,
      height: height + margin.bottom,
    })

var masked = svg.append("g")
  .attr("clip-path", "url(#mask)")

masked.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

var allStates = masked
  .append("g")
    .attr("class", "allStates");

  var state = svg.selectAll(".state")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "state")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x0(d.State) + ",0)"; });

 var state = allStates.selectAll(".state")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "state")
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x0(d.State) + ",0)"; });

  state.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) { return d.ages; })
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.name); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });
var legnColorGap=height/17.5;
  var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
      .data(ageNames.slice().reverse())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * legnColorGap + ")"; });
var lwidth=width/75 , lht=height/22,lwidth1=lwidth+2;
  legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width - lwidth1)
      .attr("width", lwidth)
      .attr("height", lht)
      .style("fill", color);
var textht=lht/2,textwd=textht+lwidth;
  legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - textwd)
      .attr("y", textht)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(function(d) { return d; });
 function zoom() {
svg.select(".allStates").attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate[0]+",0)scale(" + d3.event.scale + ",1)");
svg.select(".x.axis").attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate[0]+","+(height)+")").call(xAxis.scale(x0.rangeRoundBands([0, width * d3.event.scale],.5 * d3.event.scale)));
svg.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable panning events by adding by changing

.call(d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([1, 10]).on("zoom", zoom));

to

.call(d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([1, 10]).on("zoom", zoom)).on("mousedown.zoom", null);

Comment: I don not want to disable it but to restrict it. so that the bars don't disappear completely while dragging

Comment: if i am disabling the dragging then after zooming i can only see some of the bars in in graph  to see other bars i need dragging option. Is there any way like adding a scrolling option to view all the bars.

Comment: If you are zooming the bar graph in my code you can see that if i am disabling the dragging then after zooming i can only see one states data o in graph  to see states bars i need dragging option. Is there any way like adding a scrolling option to view all the states data.

Comment: Then, u'll have to set limits on the panning behavior. Check this link :http://bl.ocks.org/garrilla/11280861